# Zedgraph, values of logarithmic x-axis repeat again

Tags: zedgraph

I set the x-axis as logarithmic scale. The maximum value is 10000 and the minimum value is 1.

```
GraphPane mypane = zedgraphcontrol.GraphPane;
mypane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 1;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 10000;
```

But then the graph looks like this :

[image]

The values : 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4 repeat at least 2 times. It looks like 2 x-axis overlap each other.
Can anyone tell me what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's just a glitch, I found a workaround by calling AxisChange() before setting the Min and Max:

```
mypane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;
mypane.AxisChange();
mypane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 1;
mypane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 10000;
```